# Prevent div from exceeding screen

Tags: css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I have a div that is displaying under the button.
Works file as long as the button is on the left side of the screen. But if the button is on the right the box exceeds the size of the screen.

I would like the box to try to display under the button and right if possible.
But if not possible to be only as much as needed into the screen to the left so that the right edge of the modal div would be the edge of the screen.
Preferbly jQLite if possible.

Hope this makes sense and someone can help.

[image: Currenty]

**The Markup:**

```
.dd-combo .dd-combo-wrapper {
    z-index: 10;
    text-align: left;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    position: absolute;
    max-width: 1024px;
    min-width: 900px;
    min-height:300px;
    max-height:600px;
    top: 100%;
    left: -250px;
    right:10px;
    width: 1700%;
    margin: 5px auto; 
    box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #888;
    overflow:scroll;
    border-top: 1px solid #ddd;
    border-left: 1px solid #ddd;
}
.dd-combo .dd-combo-wrapper:before {
    content: '';
    display: none;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-left: 10px solid transparent;
    border-right: 10px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 11px solid #BF1E4B;
    position: absolute;
    top: -10px;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -10px;
}
```

Comment: does the buttons class, or anything change depending on whether the button is on the left or right side of the screen?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of a straight way to do it with only CSS if the button can be anywhere on the screen and not change class based on its left or right position. If I was going to do it in javascript I'd do something like:

```
function whenMenuOpens(){
  if(theMenu.getBoundingClientRect().right > window.innerWidth){
    theMenu.css({'position':'fixed', 'right':0});
    //or relative with an offset of the difference in overlap, etc
  }else{
    //whatever you were doing before
  }
}
```